# how to find maximum value of UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> with bufferSize of data type UInt32 in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, cocoapods, nspointerarray

I am new to swift and working on a project where i had to visualize audio waves!
I am using EZAudio pod where to plot the waves on the screen a function UpdatePlot is used and in parameter a UnsafeMutablePoiter> is passed 
I want the maximum value in each UnUnsafeMutablePointer to find the highest wave length on the plot

```
buffer[0]//with a bufferSize UInt32
```

I want to find the highest value in that buffer[0] array!

Please Help!!!
p.s : thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for the array buffer[]

Swift 3:

```
buffer.max()
```

Swift 2:

```
buffer.maxElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are so confusing:

> ```
> buffer[0]//with a bufferSize UInt32
> ```
>
> I want to find the highest value in that buffer[0] array!

Which is an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`, `buffer` itself or `buffer[0]`? Is `buffer` a Swift `Array`?

I assume `buffer` is of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`.

Manually:

```
func myMax(buf: UnsafePointer<Float>, count: UInt32) -> Float? {
    guard case let bufCount = Int(count) where count > 0 else {return nil}
    var max = -Float.infinity
    for i in 0..<bufCount {
        if buf[i] > max {
            max = buf[i]
        }
    }
    return max
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if let maxValue = myMax(buffer, count: bufferSize) {
    //Use the maximum value
    print(maxValue)
} else {
    //No maximum value when empty
    print("empty")
}
```

If you want to utilize Swift Library, you can write `myMax` as:

```
func myMax(buf: UnsafePointer<Float>, count: UInt32) -> Float? {
    return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf, count: Int(count)).maxElement()
}
```